# Extrude 2d polygon into 3d polygon

Tags: sql, database, geospatial, postgis

I am using postgresql and I have a table containing 2d polygons (PostGIS geometry type). Now my question is how can I extrude this polygon into a nice 3d building.?

Can anyone help please? because I couldn't find a good tutorial on it.

Many thanks

Comment: An example of the schema you're storing the data in would be useful, and some data to go along with it. Further, are you using PostGIS' or PostgreSQL's polygon data types?

Comment: I am using postgis data types